# Basic subspaces

Tags: vector-spaces, solution-verification

I'm beginning studying vectorial spaces and I'm wondering about theses spaces:

$\text{Among these subsets of} \ \mathbb{R^3}, \ \text{which one are subspaces ?}$

1) $E{_1}= ((a+b,a-b,2a); \ a,b  \in \mathbb{R})$

.$(0,0,0) \ \in \ E_1$

.Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \ (x_1,x_2) \ \in E_1$
Then $(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2) \ \in \mathbb{R^4}$ such as :

$x_1=(a_1+b_1, a_1-b_1, 2a1)$ and $x_2=(a_2+b_2, a_2-b_2, 2a2)$

Thus $\lambda x_1+x_2=(\lambda(a_1+b_1)+a_2+b_2, \lambda(a_1-b_1)+a_2-b_2, 2a_1+2a_2)=((\lambda a_1 + a_2)+(\lambda b_1 +b_2), (\lambda a_1+a_2)-(\lambda b_1 +b_2),2(a_1+a_2))$

Thus $E_1$ is a subspace.

2)$E_2=((a+b),a-b,2a+1); a,b \ \in \ \mathbb{R})$

.$(0,0,0) \ \notin \ E_2$ so this is not a subspace.

3)$E_3=(a^2+b, b, 0); a, b \ \in \mathbb{R})$

.$(0,0,0) \ \in \ E_3$

.Let $\lambda \ \in \ \mathbb{R}, (x_1,x_2) \ \in \ E_3$
Then $(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2) \ \in \mathbb{R^4}$ such as :

$x_1=((a_1^2+b_1),b_1,0)$ and $x_2=((a_2^2+b_2),b_2,0)$

Then $\lambda x_1+x_2=(\lambda a_1^2 + \lambda b_1 +a_2^2+b_2,\lambda b_1 +b_2, 0)$

I have a doubt about this one, is it a subspace ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for $E_3$: Take a look at the vectors $(1,0,0)$ and $(-1,0,0)$.